# FPDF/FPDI how to change Metadata of existing PDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

Is it possible to do:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile($pdfpfad);
$pdf->SetTitle(...);
$pdf->SetAuthor(...);
$pdf->SetSubject(...);
$pdf->SetKeywords(...);
$pdf->SetCreator(...);
```

and save the file without importing the whole PDF? I want to change only the Metadata of existing files.

Answer (score 0):

[It is impossible to edit a PDF file with FPDI.](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/can-i-edit-a-pdf-document-with-fpdi/#question-82)

> FPDI extracts and imports single pages of existing documents into a structure which can be re-used by FPDF. The resulting PDF created by FPDF/FPDI is a completely new document.[...]

Comment: Thank you ... I was afraid of that.